# Static IP address on eth1 in linux

Tags: linux, networking, beagleboneblack

I need to set a static IP address on the eth1 interface after boot up. However, on bootup the device always has a different IP address than the one configured in the /etc/network/interfaces. This is a linux OS on beagle bone.

```
##connman: WiFi
#
#connmanctl
#connmanctl> tether wifi off
#connmanctl> enable wifi
#connmanctl> scan wifi
#connmanctl> services
#connmanctl> agent on
#connmanctl> connect wifi_*_managed_psk
#connmanctl> quit

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.169.5.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# Used by: /opt/scripts/boot/autoconfigure_usb0.sh
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

The ifconfig output is as follows

```
root@beaglebone:/opt/scripts/boot# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:a3:16:e1:5d:39
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST DYNAMIC  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:173

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:c9:d0:29:e0:88
          inet addr:169.254.84.230  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::22c9:d0ff:fe29:e088/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST DYNAMIC  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6708 (6.5 KiB)  TX bytes:36844 (35.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:236 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:236 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:18852 (18.4 KiB)  TX bytes:18852 (18.4 KiB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:a3:16:e1:5d:3b
          inet addr:192.168.7.2  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a3:16ff:fee1:5d3b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:492 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:74285 (72.5 KiB)  TX bytes:98066 (95.7 KiB)

usb1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:a3:16:e1:5d:3e
          inet addr:192.168.6.2  Bcast:192.168.6.3  Mask:255.255.255.252
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a3:16ff:fee1:5d3e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:39046 (38.1 KiB)  TX bytes:13030 (12.7 KiB)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is not about programming, so it is off-topic for this site. That said, are you sure you are editing the right file for your linux distro? Not all linux flavors use `/etc/network/interfaces`, so tell us what version of linux you are using, it is important for people trying to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I am using the following version

root@beaglebone:/etc/network# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.54-ti-r93 (root@a4-imx6q-wandboard-2gb) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) ) #1 SMP Fri Mar 17 13:08:22 UTC 2017

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add network address, gateway and DNS settings also, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470237/assigning-a-static-ip-to-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts). And then restart the server using below command.

```
sudo service networking restart
```

or

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 down
sudo ifconfig eth1 up
```

Comment: Be careful answering questions like these. Some in the community feel answers should be downvoted, too. Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)

Comment: Gosh.. I didn't know that. I am new to the community sorry about that. I will go through guidelines once. Thanks jww.

Comment: I tried adding the network address and gateway and DNS settings. I am still getting the same results.

The etc/network/interfaces file is as below

    auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.3.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.3.0
        gateway 192.168.3.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

    # Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
    # Used by: /opt/scripts/boot/autoconfigure_usb0.sh
    iface usb0 inet static
        address 192.168.7.2
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        network 192.168.7.0
        gateway 192.168.7.1